# I dont have a close button

Tags: winapi

I am having a problem with my code it doesnt show the close button

```
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM );

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst , HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR args,int ncmdshow)
{
    WNDCLASSW wc = {0};

    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW ;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW) ;
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"myWindowClass";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;

    if(!RegisterClassW(&wc))
    return -1;

    CreateWindowW(L"myWindowClass",L"HI THIS IS A TEST",WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,100,100,500,500,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL );

    MSG msg = {NULL};
    while(GetMessageA(&msg,NULL,NULL,NULL) )
        {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    return 0;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wp,LPARAM lp)
{
    switch ( msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd,msg,wp,lp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using [`WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles), which does not have system menu. Use [`WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles) instead.

`WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` is equivalent to:

```
(WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX)
```

Comment: Thanks alot it was just a spelling mistake